# My Github link keeps referring to an HTML page that I've already deleted

Tags: html, git, github, github-pages

I am extremely new to coding and still learning the ins and outs of Git and Github. I am having an issue where my Github pages opens to an .html file that I deleted rather than my index.html. I am at a blockage where I've typed my question into google in various forms and have tried to figure this issue out myself, but with my limited knowledge, I'll be honest I'm just getting confused and finding myself heading down a rabbit hole. Can anyone help me out?

This is my github repo https://github.com/khayes8/Triviagame
and this is my github pages link https://khayes8.github.io/Triviagame/Finalscore.html

Comment: DId you commit into the right branch, i.e. `gh-pages` instead of `master`?

Comment: Well, the file is gone now, I guess it takes a few minutes sometimes. Have you tried emptying your browser cache (or reload using CTRL+F5)?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Answer (score 0):

In correct url of your Github Page is `https://khayes8.github.io/Trivia-game/index.html`

And I found a javascript in the repository which file `/assets/javascript/app.js` at line 69.

`setTimeout(function(){
window.location.href='Finalscore.html'});`

The statement redirect your page from `/index.html` to `/Finalscore.html`. Because you are already deleted Finalscore.html  so you will get a 404 no found page.

Comment: I fixed line 69 in my code and made sure that Finalscore.html is deleted from my local repository so when I committed my changes to github and there is no Finalscore.html file in m github repo or link to it in my app.js file, I am still getting the same page when I go into my github settings and click on the link in my github pages which is this one...https://khayes8.github.io/Triviagame/Finalscore.html
when I try to open up https://khayes8.github.io/Triviagame/ or replace Finalscore.html with Index.html it still goes to the same page.

Comment: @KelseyHayes Hey, I saw your website. have you already solved the problem?